# how to call one class method into another class by using loop with example

Tags: community

****Hi all*,***
**I have two classes and i want to dispaly 1st class method(getContacts) in second class for loop how can i achieve it.............**

1.first class :

```
public class AccountRelatedContactsOpportunities {
public List<Contact> getContacts() {
List<Contact> conresults = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName,Title,Email from Contact];
return conresults;
}
}
```

2.second class:

```
public class testvf {
if {
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method you want to call is void, then you can call with class instanse and method name. If the method is static then class name.method name

```
public class testvf {

AccountRelatedContactsOpportunities objClassInstance = new AccountRelatedContactsOpportunities();

    list<Contact> lstContact = objClassInstance.getContacts(); 
}
```

Comment: hi Rashmi,                                                                                                                  
thank for you are code i have gone trough your code .......                                                        i am facing error.................missing')' in statement

Comment: Please try again and let me know which line you are facing error

Comment: hi rashmi,                                                                                                                                 thanks for you code but how can we insert records using for loop.................

Comment: You should bulkify the insertion. Iterating individual database inserts is the wrong approach. You need to collect a list of items to insert and perform a single insertion once all data is constructed.