# how to call one class method into another class by using loop with examples

Tags: community

****Hi all*,* **I have two classes and i want to dispaly 1st class method(doInsert) in second class for loop how can i achieve it.............

First class :

```
public with sharing class DataLoadTestingClass {
public String phoneVal { get; set; }
public String countryVal { get; set; }
public String cityVal { get; set; }
public String nameVal { get; set; }

public list<DataloadTest__c>  doInsert() {
List<DataloadTest__c> objdlt = new List<DataloadTest__c>();
    DataloadTest__c dl=new DataloadTest__c();
dl.name=nameVal;
dl.city__c=cityVal;
dl.country__c=countryVal;
dl.phone__c=phoneVal;
    objdlt.add(dl);
insert objdlt;
//pagereference ref = new pagereference('/apex/insertdlttest');
//ref.setredirect(true);
return objdlt;
}
}
```

second class :

```
public class testvf1 {
DataLoadTestingClass objClassInstance = new DataLoadTestingClass();
list<DataloadTest__c> lstContact = objClassInstance.doInsert(); 
}
```

Comment: This question is almost identical to your [previous one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289705/how-to-call-one-class-method-into-another-class-by-using-loop-with-example). It's also quite unclear, since you do not have a `for` loop in either class.  If you are new to core Apex syntax, please refer to the [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm) or the intro modules on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database).

Comment: I've put this question on hold for now. Please use an [edit] to clarify exactly what you are asking so that a satisfactory answer can be identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the method of first class in the below way:

```
public with sharing class DataLoadTestingClass {
public String phoneVal { get; set; }
public String countryVal { get; set; }
public String cityVal { get; set; }
public String nameVal { get; set; }

public DataloadTest__c  doInsert() {

DataloadTest__c dl=new DataloadTest__c();
dl.name=nameVal;
dl.city__c=cityVal;
dl.country__c=countryVal;
dl.phone__c=phoneVal;

return objdlt;
//pagereference ref = new pagereference('/apex/insertdlttest');
//ref.setredirect(true);

}
}

public class testvf1 {

    public void insData(){
        DataLoadTestingClass objClassInstance = new DataLoadTestingClass();
        list<DataloadTest__c> lstContact = new list<DataloadTest__c>();
        for(integer i=0;i<100;i++){

            DataloadTest__c objDL = objClassInstance.doInsert(); 
            lstContact.add(objDL);
        }
        insert lstContact;
    }
}
```

In above I have iterated 100 times, but that can be done based on any criteria

Comment: hi rashmi,                                                                                                                                                                     error messsage : Expecting '}' but was: 'for'

Comment: Please share what you tried and what error you faced clearly